# Get the FacebookProfile for a particular time duration : spring social for facebook

Tags: java, facebook, spring-social-facebook

I am trying to get the FacebookProfile for a particular time duration.

```
String token="?";//Facebook access token
Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(token);
List<FacebookProfile> profiles = friendOperations.getFriendProfiles();
```

Here I am getting the all FacebookProfile who are my friends. My requirement is to get only those profile who became the friends in particular year of month.